# Android & Eclipse Error: Could not find class 'com.dropbox.client2.session.AppKeyPair'

Tags: android, eclipse, dropbox

I'm making an Android App using Eclipse. I want to implement a feature that shares a file on my dropbox account so I downloaded the sdk.

I'm following official documentation here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/authentication#android

so I wrote this code in Import Section:

```
import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
import com.dropbox.client2.android.AndroidAuthSession;
import com.dropbox.client2.session.AppKeyPair;
import com.dropbox.client2.session.Session.AccessType;
```

This code in classe declaration

```
final static private String APP_KEY = "*****";
final static private String APP_SECRET = "****";
private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi;
```

and this code in my method:

```
com.dropbox.client2.session.AppKeyPair appKeys = new com.dropbox.client2.session.AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys,AccessType.APP_FOLDER);
mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
```

But when I debug first line of method I have this error:

```
01-02 17:07:54.459: E/dalvikvm(19602): Could not find class 'com.dropbox.client2.session.AppKeyPair', referenced from method com.example.myfirstapp.DbAccess.ShareDbOnDropbox
```

Please, can you help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: make sure the jar is added and exported during compilation

Answer (score 0):

When adding the `.jar` file to your project, do you **export the jar** on the build path?

Right click your project in Eclipse, select `Properties`, then select `Java Build Path`. Navigate to the `Order and Export` tab and make sure that the **Dropbox library is ticked**.

This exports the classes for use in your project when the application is compiled and built.

Click `Ok`, then do a clean build and try again.

Comment: Thank you biddulph.r! It work! The error no longer occurs, but does not do what I expect. Now I do some tests and let you know. For now, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
 com.dropbox.client2.session.AppKeyPair appKeys = new com.dropbox.client2.session.AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
```

to this:

```
 AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
```

in Eclipse press

```
 ctrl + shift + O
```

this will organise your imports and bring in the correct DropBox class, if it does then yay fixed. If it doesn't then your class path is not setup correctly and your project can't find the dropbox lib/jar/sdk.

Comment: not really. according to dropbox documentation, that's the correct qualified name.

Comment: @njzk2 yes but he manually typed the imports himself, so he doesn't know if his classpath is correct or not. The outcome of ctrl+shift+O would give us this hint

Comment: it wouldn't compile if the imports were wrong. the issue here is obviously about exporting at compile time.

Comment: @njzk2 good point :-p I was just thinking some people don't actually realise when they have compile errors, but yeah his issue is not compile time it's run time

Comment: Blundell, thi fix don't solve the problem. Originally the code was like the one you posted, I changed it to try. Thanks anyway