# Estimote/iBeacon not Region class found in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, classnotfoundexception, ibeacon, estimote

I'm trying to do a simple app to raging beacons, but It stops when I launch the app. I think I imported the sdk properly, with "add external jar".

[image: sdk imported]

I changed android manifest to do bluetooth permissions and other things...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
...
<service android:name="com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService" android:exported="false"/>
```

This is the error log:

```
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/dalvikvm(9326): Could not find class 'com.estimote.sdk.Region', referenced from method com.example.beacons.MainActivity.<clinit>
02-25 13:25:45.431: W/dalvikvm(9326): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 710 (Lcom/estimote/sdk/Region;) in Lcom/example/beacons/MainActivity;
02-25 13:25:45.431: D/dalvikvm(9326): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0001
02-25 13:25:45.431: D/dalvikvm(9326): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x13b3 at 0x07 in Lcom/example/beacons/MainActivity;.<clinit>
02-25 13:25:45.431: W/dalvikvm(9326): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lcom/example/beacons/MainActivity;
02-25 13:25:45.431: W/dalvikvm(9326): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/example/beacons/MainActivity;)
02-25 13:25:45.431: D/AndroidRuntime(9326): Shutting down VM
02-25 13:25:45.431: W/dalvikvm(9326): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41599ba8)
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326): Process: com.example.beacons, PID: 9326
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.estimote.sdk.Region
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326):     at com.example.beacons.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:18)
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-25 13:25:45.431: E/AndroidRuntime(9326):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 13:30:45.704: I/Process(9326): Sending signal. PID: 9326 SIG: 9
```

I don't know why it says could't not find class 'com.estimote.sdk.Region'...

This is the main activity

```
package com.example.beacons;

import java.util.List;

import com.estimote.sdk.Beacon;
import com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager;
import com.estimote.sdk.Region;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID = "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D";
    private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS = new Region("regionId", ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID, null, null);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void bluetoothTest(View view){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Listener works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

If I delete this line:

```
private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS = new Region("regionId", ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID, null, null);
```

All works fine and I can see the toast when touching 1 button I have in the screen.

Answer (score 1):

It's Eclipse that for some reason is not packing jar into an apk.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11003202 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/14125846 or [referencing (pure java) project in Android project (Could not find class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079726/referencing-pure-java-project-in-android-project-could-not-find-class)

Answer (score 1):

I was with your same trouble.
in my case was with Unity3D and estimote service.
The key is to add a fragment without UI to the currentActivity.

exemple: this in a file that starts beacons. in your case if you are doing this from an activity you can erase UnityPlayer.currentActivity, as this example is for mixing with a unity project

```
    fragment = new BeaconsFragment();
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(fragment, "thread_beacons");
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
```